# Using maven properties plugin to read database info

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm trying to read the database properties file to initialize my database and I'm using maven. So I specified following plugin in my pom.xml:

```
     <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-alpha-1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <files>
                <file>${basedir}/src/resources/database.properties</file>
                <file>${basedir}/src/resources/databaseTest.properties</file>
              </files>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

But I don't know how to load it properly in the code, I send "/database.properties" as a parameter to my loading method here, but it doesn't work:

```
public static DatabaseSetting loadSettings(String dbPropertiesName)  {
        String dbPropertiesPath = DatabaseSetting.class.getResource
                (dbPropertiesName).getPath();
        Properties dbProperties = new Properties();
        try {
            dbProperties.load(new FileInputStream(new File(dbPropertiesPath)));
            String host = dbProperties.getProperty("host");
            String username = dbProperties.getProperty("username");
            String password = dbProperties.getProperty("password");
            String databaseName = dbProperties.getProperty("databaseName");
            String table = dbProperties.getProperty("table");
            return new DatabaseSetting(databaseName, host, username,
                    password, table);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading database configuration " +
                   "file.");
        }
    }
```

This works fine in IntelliJ, but when I package it in maven and run it, I get following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Error loading database configuration file.

Comment: What is the message in `e` the `IOException` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be misunderstanding the point of the Maven properties plugin, and I believe it is unnecessary here, but more on that later.

With the little bit that you have posted, I can wager a guess at why it is not loading the properties file.

The `IOException` caught is most likely a `FileNotFoundException`. It looks like you have placed your properties files in `src/resources`, but per [Maven convention](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html), they should be in `src/main/resources`.

Move your properties files there, and they should now properly be on the classpath. In addition, there might be a cleaner way to retrieve the properties:

```
dbProperties.load(DatabaseSetting.class.getResourceAsStream(dbPropertiesName));
```

**Maven Properties Plugin**

Because, it appears like you are simply attempting to load properties from a file to use at runtime, the Maven properties plugin is unnecessary here. As configured, this plugin will merely load the properties into the Maven build context, but it does not help in any way to load the properties in your program. You can safely delete the plugin declaration from your pom.

Comment: Thank you, I believe it's fixed now. I think I missed the point that maven default resources has to be in src/main/resources.